# How to go to the file by clicking on the link? (ctrl+click)

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

How to make WebStorm to pass along such paths on `Ctrl+Click`?

```
  {% include "content/content_index.twig" %} - not work
  {% include "content_index.twig" %} -  working
```

[image]

Comment: Question resolved!
{% include "../content/content_index.twig" %} - working

Comment: "./content_index.twig" ?